# Jenkins - how to restrict job modify to owner only

Tags: jenkins

we are using Jenkins with a "Role Strategy" and owner plugins installed. So we are managing folders:
Folder_A - contains team A jobs get
Folder_B - contains team B jobs.
everyone can see all jobs but only AD team A can modify Folder_A.
I would like to add some restrictions so only an owner of some job can modify it.
Additionally, team A member can modify a Folder_A name and that is also not acceptable. So maybe by setting Folder ownership to admin, it will be fine.
Is that possible? I read about macros support in the Role strategy but didn't really get how to use it.